# Library conflict when using both std_logic_arith and numeric_std

Tags: vhdl

Is it possible to declare the `std_logic_arith` arithmetic library with the `numeric_std` library together?

Because when I removed them the code didn't work, but when I used them both it gives an error that there is a conflict between these two libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `std_logic_arith` and the `numeric_std` packages declare for example a type named `unsigned`.

So if you `use` both packages with `.all`, then you are very likely to run into conflicts.

Suggestion is to use only the IEEE standard package `numeric_std`, and skip using the non-standard package `std_logic_arith`.  Despite the location in the `ieee` library, the `std_logic_arith` package is not VHDL standard, but an open source package from Synopsys.